# Github for Windows - "The requested URL returned error: 403" - persistent issue after changing remote server

Tags: git, authorization, github-for-windows

- My commpany was using Azure Mobile Service with certain name
- Because of file-system corruption on Azure Mobile Service we were forced to delete and recreate Mobile Service in other subscription
- I'm using GitHub for Windows for Git shell (enhanced Powershell) on Windows7.
- I can't push to or pull from this repository (it's only HTTPS access)
- I can push to or pull from this repository from my coworker computer (he is using normal ms-git)

Basic error returned:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://my_new_name@abcd.scm.azure-mobile.net/abcd.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

With verbose curl, interesting fragments:

```
* Server auth using Basic with user 'new_user_name'
> GET /abcd.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1

< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
....
< WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="site"

* Couldn't find host abcd.scm.azure-mobile.net in the _netrc file; using defaults
* Found bundle for host abcd.scm.azure-mobile.net: 0x1f6b538
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host abcd.scm.azure-mobile.net
* Connected to abcd.scm.azure-mobile.net (23.102.12.43) port 443 (#0)
...
* Server auth using Basic with user 'old_user_name'
```

Both push and fetch does not work, neither clone. I'm NOT prompted for password, just rejected. How can I reset these credentials? Following solutions did not work:

- uninstall Github for Windows and reinstall it
- trying to switch to SSH push/pull - isn't supported by Azure
- setting https://youruser:password@URL as remote URL
- `git config --global --unset core.askpass`
- changing credential store

Additional data:

```
git version 1.9.5.github.0
curl 7.30.0 (i386-pc-win32) libcurl/7.30.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8{ zlib/1.2.7
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS GSS-Negotiate IPv6 Largefile NTLM SPNEGO SSL SSPI libz
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using Git Bash: https://git-scm.com/download/win
I ran into same issue with Git Hub recently. It worked fine with Git Bash.